# Replace a string with nothing if it contains '$' character

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a multi line string i want to remove a line in a string if that line contains '$' character.

Sample String :-
       `<ecm:Field name="X_LastMobileNumChange_detail">NA</ecm:Field>
                <ecm:Field name="X_ModeOfOperation">SELF</ecm:Field>
                <ecm:Field name="X_DrawingPower">210000.0000</ecm:Field>
                <ecm:Field name="${/ecmi/}"></ecm:Field>
                <ecm:Field name="X_DrawingPower">210000.0000</ecm:Field>`

So the above string is a sample string. So in this case i want to remove line 4 because it contains '$'. Can someone please help me in writing regular expression for this.

Comment: Could you please for a start format your code in a way, so one knows what line 4 is? I would do it for you, but I honestly can't guess.

Comment: @Aaron there is no compulson of using regex i just want to remove the line from the string which contains '$' character. My string is a multi-line string.

Comment: @kai my sample string is a multi-line string as given in that sample if you see line 4 its contains '$' value so now i want to remove th enitre line from the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = s.replaceAll(".*\\$.*(\\R|$)", "");
```

- `\R` matches a line ending (`\n` or `\r\n` or some others).
- `\\$` matches the dollar symbol itself.
- `.`  any char, by default however not the newline chars.
- `(\\R|$)` the last line does not need to end with a newline $ = end of string.

Comment: i m not getting the desire result s = s.replaceAll(".*\\$.*\\R", "")  giving me the same string in result . The string i m testing on is   this "/ecmi/alerts/$alert/demographic/item[6]/";

Comment: Ah, the last line is not terminated with a newline. Changed the answer.